# Syncing chrome extension data without publishing

Tags: javascript, html, json, google-chrome-extension

I have recently created my first personal chrome extension and I wonder if it is possible to have its updates synced between two computers without publishing it? I tried googling this issue, but couldn't find a discussion on it.

Comment: updates as in new version update or settings?

Comment: Maybe using an external `update_url` can work... But haven't tried it.

Comment: Consider asking this question in [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)